# How to free the Heap Memory occupied some Wild Pointers and other dynamic pointers in C#

Tags: c#, memory, dynamic, window, heap-memory

I am using C# for Windows Form Base Application. When we create a new form on button click like:

```
Form f = new Form();
```

It takes place in heap Memory. So , How can I Delete this Memory and all Dynamically Created Memory by my App?

Is this : Application.Exit()  does work to delete Heap Memory.

Comment: by letting the garbage collection do its work? i'm sorry, but i'm not really sure what you are getting at. could you be more precise about what exactly the problem is you're trying to solve?

Comment: C# memory management by default is none of your business. If you  want to use C# (as opposed to c or c++) you should not mess with its features.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately: "do nothing; let the GC worry about it". However, since forms are disposable, it would be a good idea to ensure it gets disposed. If you are displaying this form modally, then a `using` statement/block should be sufficient. If you're not using it modally, it is a little trickier, but not much - just hook the close event. Other than that, just make sure that *you have no references to the form*. Again, if you are using it modally, this probably isn't an issue because `f` is probably a local variable that will go out of scope at the right time. If `f` is a field (perhaps for a non-modal form), then just assign `null` to it after you've disposed it.

Emphasis: managed GC is non-deterninistic. It will decide when to actually collect things, but we can make sure we're not keeping things alive unnecessary, as above.